# React.js Display a component with onClick event

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, error-handling

I' m new to React and I'm building a simple React app that displays all the nations of the world on the screen and a small search bar that shows the data of the searched nation.

[Here an image of the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyDzG.png)

But I don't know how to show the country you want to click in the scrollbar.

Here the app.js code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import NavBar from '../Components/NavBar';
import SideBar from './SideBar';
import CountryList from '../Components/SideBarComponents/CountryList';
import Scroll from '../Components/SideBarComponents/Scroll';
import Main from './Main';
import SearchCountry from '../Components/MainComponents/SearchCountry';
import SearchedCountry from '../Components/MainComponents/SearchedCountry';
import Datas from '../Components/MainComponents/Datas';

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      nations: [],
      searchField: '',
      button: false
    }
  }

  onSearchChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({searchField: event.target.value});
    console.log(this.state.searchField)
  }

  onClickChange = () => {
    this.setState(prevsState => ({
      button: true
    }))
  }

  render() {

    const {nations, searchField, button, searchMemory} = this.state;

    const searchedNation = nations.filter(nation => {
      if(button) {
        return nation.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase())
      }
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <NavBar/>
        </div>
          <Main>
            <div className='backgr-img'>
              <SearchCountry searchChange={this.onSearchChange} clickChange={this.onClickChange}/>
              <SearchedCountry nations={searchedNation}/>
            </div>
             <Datas nations={searchedNation}/>
          </Main>
          <SideBar>
            <Scroll className='scroll'>
              <CountryList nations={nations} clickFunc/>
            </Scroll>
          </SideBar>
      </div>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
     fetch('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(x => this.setState({nations: x}));
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.state.button = false;
  }

}

export default App;
```

The countryList:

```
import React from 'react';
import Images from './Images';

const CountryList = ({nations, clickFunc}) => {
    return (
        <div className='container' style={{display: 'grid', gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(auto-fill, minmax(115px, 3fr))'}}>
            {
                nations.map((country, i) => {
                    return (
                        <Images 
                        key={country.numericCode}
                        name={country.name}
                        flag={country.flag}
                        clickChange={clickFunc}
                        />
                    );
                })
            }
        </div>
    )                   
}
export default CountryList;
```

And the images.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './images.css'

const Images = ({name, capital, region, population, flag, numericCode, clickChange}) => {
    return (
        <div className='hover bg-navy pa2 ma1 tc w10' onClick={clickChange = () => name}>
            <img alt='flag' src={flag} />
            <div>
                <h6 className='ma0 white'>{name}</h6>
                {capital}
                {region}
                {population}
                {numericCode}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Images;
```

I had thought of using the onClick event on the single nation that was going to return the name of the clicked nation. After that I would have entered the name in the searchField and set the button to true in order to run the searchedNation function.
I thank anyone who gives me an answer in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep the actual structure, you can try using `onClickChange` in Images:

```
onClickChange = (newName = null) => {
  if(newName) {
    this.setState(prevsState => ({
      searchField: newName
    }))
  }
  // old code continues
  this.setState(prevsState => ({
    button: true
  }))

}
```

then in onClick of Images you call:

`onClick={() => {clickChange(name)}}`

Or you can try as well use react hooks (but this will require some refactoring) cause you'll need to change a property from a parent component.
With that you can use [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook to change the value from parent component (from Images to App):

`const [searchField, setSearchField] = useState('');`

Then you pass setSearchField to images as props and changes the searchField value when Images is clicked:

```
onClick={() => {
    clickChange()
    setSearchField(name)
}}
```

Comment: When I call onClick of Images as you told me, I get this error: TypeError: clickChange is not a function
This is how I declared clickChange (i think the error comes from here but i don't know how to declare correctly):

`const Images = ({name, capital, region, population, flag, numericCode, clickChange}) => { ...`

Comment: I fixed the error, I had to import the App into Images, now it works, thanks a lot :)